# Showing error when Installing ubuntu on my HP Probook 450 G2

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, hp, bios

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my HP Pro-book 450 G2.

But after booting when I select Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu it takes some time and goes to a black screen and then shows the Ubuntu loading screen for few seconds and then returns to the black screen again and finally stays there.

And there are some errors in this screen.

1. [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
2. [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
3. amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: Fatal error during GPU init

So I have turned of hybrid GPU from my bios and then tried again. And this time only number 1 error from the above was shown repeatedly. Every time I tried to boot this error was showing.

And I was left in the initramfs command line... I don't know how to fix this issue.

IS there any solution to this problem?

How can I install Ubuntu on this laptop?
Will be waiting for your answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to do two things to get an installation of Ubuntu (not a dual boot) to boot straight Ubuntu.

1. Go into the bios and make sure that in "Boot Mode" "UEFI Native (without CSM)" is selected. So NOT "legacy" or "UEFI Hybrid (with CSM)".
2. Also in the bios, use a customized boot option. Add as the path in the box that appears when you click on the option (leave off the double quotes when enetering) "\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi". That is for when secure boot is not selected. If secure boot is selected, I think it should be "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi", but I didn't try that.

Before I did 1, the boot did not recognise any OS at all. After 1, the computer went into a "reset system" loop and I could only boot by going to F9 in the bios and selecting Ubuntu every time. After 2, the boot to Ubuntu was automatic.